# how to force remove all media queries and just stick to one size

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

This one is going against all web design fundamentals. Basically, I was given a website that was started from desktop to mobile, only they never finished mobile or tablet. The client does not want a mobile version anymore, he just wants all screens to fit and look the same in all screen sizes. I told him, it's as easy as removing the media queries for mobile, only now that I shrink the page on my browser, the entire thing turns into a mess because the media queries for mobile are missing. What can I do? Does changing the meta tag do anything?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good article about your code: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

It will be easier if you provide more code or if you give us a link to your client's site (if it possible). However I can offer you to check your .css files for `@media` tags, look for something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1330px){
  .main{
    width:830px;
  }
  .content{
    width:480px;
  }
}
```

Also you can use `!important` property for width of some elements. It will say the element to ignore all other width value. But it is preferable not to do this and check all code manually for some css tricks that was written for mobile devices.

You can read more about `@media` here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just set a fixed width for the content container.

Comment: tried this, but its one of those websites that uses percentages. should I just change all of those?

Comment: Set it on the main wrapper and all of the relative sizes later will change accordingly.

Comment: So it looks like the only wrapper used is the body. yikes.

Comment: that is fine, you can set either a min-width or a width to the body.

Comment: ok ok thats weird, it's not showing up on mobile anymore. it looks fine on desktop, but it disappeared completely on mobile!